# Thread.sleep in loop not working, any alternatives?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

Been told thread.sleep() in a loop isn't allowed, but I need to use this as I'm calling a socket which has a limit per second.

Any other way of doing it?

```
for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(300);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(bulkWhoIsCommand.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: A limit of what per second?

Comment: Why isn't `Thread.sleep` allowed?

Comment: Any problem with `Timer` or `ScheduledExectorService`?

Comment: What kind of problems are you facing? Is it a compiler error or does the code just not work as expected?

Comment: Who told you that `Thread.sleep()` is not allowed?

Comment: @DavidWallace - `Thread.sleep()` is **discouraged** because it **usually** indicates that your code is designed wrong. It is rare for a correctly implemented algorithm to require you to pause a thread.

Comment: @TonyEnnis - *I'm surprised you didn't...* Please do not feed the trolls/tourists/lions.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I understand that.  But there are some circumstances when a good Thread's sleep is exactly what is required.  I'd say that this kind of arbitrary throttling is one such case, but I'm open to being educated.  This time, of course, I was mostly trying to ascertain whether this was a homework assignment in which the teacher had said "don't use sleep".

Comment: @DavidWallace Trust me, this isn't homework. Stupid socket application is throttling amount of requests.

Comment: Does it somehow indicate when a request has been throttled?  Or do you just have to guess?

Comment: Why the loop? Why not just call `Thread.sleep(300*100)`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `poll` method of a `BlockingQueue`:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Void> pause = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Void>(1);

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    pause.poll(100 * 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

The wonder of this technique is that you can poke something down the queue to abort the pause if ever you decide to do so.

Comment: Did you mean to have it poll for 30 seconds?  The code in the question sleeps for 0.3 seconds.

Comment: @DavidWallace the OP's code performs the 0.3 second sleep 100 times = 30 seconds.

Comment: Oh, of course.  Don't know what I was thinking.  Nice technique.

Comment: diamond operator not supported I'm getting? confused

Comment: @user3504452 - The `<>` is a Java 7 feature. Use `<Void>` in earlier JDKs. Code edited.

Comment: I don’t see how abusing `BlockingQueue.poll` for doing exactly the same as `Thread.sleep` is improving the software design.

Comment: @Holger - it isn't really improving anything other than removing the nagging that many IDE's produce for using `Thread.sleep()` in a loop which is often a code smell. As I pointed out - using a `BlockingQueue` does allow you to abort the pause part-way through rather than waiting for the allotted time.

Comment: Obfuscating a sleep by a dummy queue is a far bigger code smell. By the way, you can’t put anything into a `BlockingQueue<Void>`. There are no `Void` instances and `null` is not allowed. If you want to have a sleep which can terminate earlier use either `Object.wait` or `Condition.await` as they are both *intended* for that use case.

Comment: @Holger - You are right about the `Void` point - clearly I would change that before using the queue to abort the poll. I disagree about `Condition` being the best route. Asker was just wanting to wait a while - there was no indication that there were locks involved. Introducing a `Lock` and a `try/finally` and a `Condition` just to pause for a few milliseconds seems overkill to me.

Comment: Either the asker really wants to just sleep, then the `BlockingQueue` is overkill as well and, as said, even more code smell than just using `Thread.sleep`. Or the asker wants to actually wait for something then (s)he should just `(a)wait`.